# How did Peter Quill know where the Power Stone was, even if he didn't know *what* it was?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In [*Guardians of the Galaxy* (2014)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/) Peter Quill lands on Morag with some device that let's him (I'm guessing here...) see the past as a hologram.  He uses it to find the entry to a building, and finds the Power Stone encased in a metallic orb.  He puts down a magnet, which allows the orb to be pulled from its prison and get sucked onto the magnet.

So, my question is, Quill seemed to know exactly what he was after, in terms of where it was.  He also knew exactly how to retrieve it.  Is there anything in the movie (or even in the comic backstory) that explains **why** or **how** Quill knew where the orb was, and why no one else had sought it?  It seems like kind of a huge story hole when you take the whole MCU into account.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Peter was commissioned to retrieve the orb for whoever The Broker's client was, it seems likely that The Broker told Peter where to find it.

> **The Broker:** Mr. Quill.
>
> **Peter Quill:** Broker. The orb. **As commissioned.**
>
> **The Broker:** Where’s Yondu?
>
> **Peter Quill:** Wanted to be here, sends his love. And told me to tell you, that you got the best eyebrows in the business. What is it?
>
> **The Broker:** **It’s my policy never to discuss my clients, or their needs.**
>
> **Peter Quill:** Yeah, well, I almost died getting it for you.
>
> **The Broker:** An occupational hazard, I’m sure, in your line of work.
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy*</sub>

To clarify here The Broker  commissioned Yondu and his Ravangers as a whole rather than Peter specifically but he went out of his way to get it alone for the bounty.

> **Yondu Udonta:** I’m here on Morag. Ain’t no Orb, ain’t no you.
>
> **Peter Quill:** Well, I was in the neighborhood. I thought I’d save you the hassle.
>
> **Yondu Udonta:** Well, where are you at now, boy?
>
> **Peter Quill:** I feel really bad about this, but I’m not gonna tell you that.
>
> **Yondu Udonta:** I slaved putting this deal together…
>
> **Peter Quill:** Slaved? Making a few calls is "slaved"?
>
> **Yondu Udonta:** And now you’re gonna rip me off!
>
> **Peter Quill:** I mean, really?
>
> **Yondu Udonta:** We do not do that to each other. We’re Ravagers.We got a code.
>
> **Peter Quill:**: Yeah, and that code is "steal from everybody."
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy*</sub>

Comment: So is it ever hinted at later as to who the client was?

Comment: @JohnnyBones I can't remember tbh though I suppose the Collector is a decent guess.

Comment: @JohnnyBones [This Q on scifi assumes it is The Collector too.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/65563/58193)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Carrot's excellent answer, director James Gunn had the notion that Morag was flooded a long time ago due to a natural disaster and its only on rare occasions (such as that seen at the start of the film) that the water level drops enough for the surface to be accessed (and for the 'Orb' / Power Stone to be retrieved).

Source: *Guardians Of The Galaxy* Director's Commentary with James Gunn